# Prevent like data from grouping in table? SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-tablix

I've seen how to's on how to display combined data however, I would like to keep all data separate in their own rows and columns. It seems to have to do with grouping, but when I attempt to delete the grouping, the report has an error when trying to run. [I would like to prevent the cells from combining like in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar1lb.jpg)

Comment: It's usually easier to start with a new table than try to fix an old one. When adding columns, use the Insert Column -> Left (or right) rather than Add Group.

Comment: @Hannover I've been using the table wizard in order to build these tables as I'm new to SSRS. Any idea how I can change it?

Comment: What's the error when you run the report?

Comment: @molleyc - there's no error - the OP doesn't want the grouping that the wizard was creating.

Comment: Sorry - this line copied from your original question was misleading then: "It seems to have to do with grouping, but when I attempt to delete the grouping, the report has an error when trying to run."

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a report in the wizard, any items that are set in the red **Group** section will create a new grouping.

You want to place all the fields you want to see in the blue **Detail** section of the wizard. There is no grouping in the details. If you have a group

Putting fields in the orange **Page** section will cause a new page to be created for every new value.

[image: Example wizard]

In this example, the wizard will create a report that will Page based on the **Region**. Each region will have it's own section that includes a **Vendor** group and each vendor group consists of **member claims** (it's in health care). It will create a new page for each region then group each vendor's members claim within that region.